# Guidance on implementing Okta Redirect with Docusaurus

Tags: okta, docusaurus

Having trobule implementing okta redirect with docusaurus using their documentation due to how docusaurus intiallly loads in routes. Can anyone provide any guidance on how to go about this?

https://github.com/okta/okta-react

Expected Behavior:
Initial path to load up redirects to okta and authenticates then returns back to webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and saw your posting hoping for an answer. bummer.  Then I dug around a little more. It's not fully implemented yet because I'm waiting on the okta creds from my administrators, but this got me to a permission denied screen (which is a good thing to me!)

Few things:

- docusaurus currently uses react-router-dom v5. you need to specifically set that instead of defaulting to v6
- src/pages/index.tsx (i'm using typescript) should allow you to setup a browserrouter there

react-router-dom package:

```
"react-router": "^5.3.3",
"react-router-config": "^5.1.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.3"
```

src/pages/index.tsx - I updated the home component to have a DocusaurusHome component, then made Home hold the routing logic

```
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import Link from '@docusaurus/Link';
import useDocusaurusContext from '@docusaurus/useDocusaurusContext';
import Layout from '@theme/Layout';
import HomepageFeatures from '@site/src/components/HomepageFeatures';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import styles from './index.module.css';
import { OktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-auth-js';
import { Security, LoginCallback } from '@okta/okta-react';
import { RequiredAuth } from '../components/RequiredAuth';

// file with client id
import clientId from '../Okta/OktaClientID';
// file with issuer url
import issuerUrl from '../Okta/OktaIssuerUrl';

const config = {
  clientId: clientId,
  issuer: issuerUrl,
  redirectUri: `${location.protocol}//${location.host}/callback`,
  scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
  pkce: true
};

const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth(config);

function HomepageHeader() {
  const {siteConfig} = useDocusaurusContext();
  return (
    <header className={clsx('hero hero--primary', styles.heroBanner)}>
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="hero__title">{siteConfig.title}</h1>
        <p className="hero__subtitle">{siteConfig.tagline}</p>
        <div className={styles.buttons}>
          <Link
            className="button button--secondary button--lg"
            to="/docs/intro">
            Docusaurus Tutorial - 5min ⏱️
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

/**
 * Actual Docusaurus Home component
 */
function DocusaurusHome(): JSX.Element {
  const {siteConfig} = useDocusaurusContext();
  return (<Layout
  title={`Hello from ${siteConfig.title}`}
  description="Description will go into a meta tag in <head />">
  <HomepageHeader />
  <main>
    <HomepageFeatures />
  </main>
</Layout>)
}

/**
 * component for react-router-dom browserrouter and okta auth
 */
export default function Home(): JSX.Element {

  const restore = async (_oktaAuth: OktaAuth, originalUri: string) => {
    window.location.replace(originalUri);
};

return (
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Security oktaAuth={oktaAuth} restoreOriginalUri={restore}>
              <Switch>
                  <Route path='/callback'>
                      <LoginCallback
                          errorComponent={(err) => {
                              // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                              console.error(err);
                              setTimeout(() => {
                                  localStorage.removeItem('okta-token-storage');
                                  window.location.replace(`${location.protocol}//${location.host}/`);
                              }, 2000);

                              return null;
                          }}/>
                    </Route>
                  <Route path='/'>
                    <RequiredAuth />
                  </Route>
                  <Route path='*'>
                    <DocusaurusHome />
                  </Route>
              </Switch>
      </Security>
  </BrowserRouter>);
}
```

The RequiredAuth component originally returned an react-router-dom Outlet, which doesn't exist in v5. I think that a Route *should* suffice in it's place

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useOktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-react';
import { toRelativeUrl } from '@okta/okta-auth-js';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

export const RequiredAuth: React.FC = () => {
    const { oktaAuth, authState } = useOktaAuth();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!authState) {
            return;
        }

        if (!authState?.isAuthenticated) {
            const originalUri = toRelativeUrl(window.location.href, window.location.origin);

            oktaAuth.setOriginalUri(originalUri);
            oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect();
        }
    }, [oktaAuth, !!authState, authState?.isAuthenticated]);

    if (!authState || !authState?.isAuthenticated) {
        return <></>; // loading screen before okta login
    }

    return (<Route />);
};
```